# Condition of do_group_exit() in get_signal() in Linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, signals

Can anybody explain what `do_signal()` and `get_signal()` functions do? And what does this line of code in `get_signal()` actually mean, i.e. when exactly it would run:

```
        /*
         * Death signals, no core dump.
         */
        do_group_exit(ksig->info.si_signo);
        /* NOTREACHED */
```

This is for example in: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.7/source/kernel/signal.c#L2307

Answer (score 0):

`get_signal` is arch-independent, and returns the next signal in the queue for the current task. If that signal has no handler, it does the default action, which could exit the task (e.g. on SIGSEGV or SIGKILL) with the line of code you linked to, but could also [suspend the task](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.7/source/kernel/signal.c#L2248), or [core dump the task](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.7/source/kernel/signal.c#L2289) and *then* exit.

For more on default actions, have a look at the "Standard signals" section of [signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

`do_signal` is arch-specific, and called by the arch-specific code when exiting the kernel. Its job is to call `get_signal`. If that returns a signal, meaning it's supposed to be handled by userspace, it pushes the signal handler stack frame.